# Why does my MacBookPro log me off when waking from sleep/hibernation?

Tags: windows-7, macbook

I have a MacBookPro (current generation -1).  Every time my machine falls asleep, I am logged out.  Sometimes I get a BSOD when waking up.

Here's all the additional info I have:

- When I last BSODed, it indicated that there was a problem in `atikamdg.sys` which appears to be my video card (AMD Radeon 6770M) driver.
- I have the latest driver according to AMD's Driver Autodetect.
- When I BSOD, it looks like it's creating a dump file (a counter counts to 100%), but the screen does not pause and my machine immediately reboots.  There is no dump file in `c:\windows\minidump`

I'll continue to add more debugging info as I receive it.  Please add comments if there's additional info that might be helpful.

Anyone have any idea what's going on or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you really logged out or is the screen just locked?

Comment: I am logged out.

Comment: Try [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Comment: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Do you have a screen saver? If yes, change it to "None" and see if this changes anything (screen display can be turned off in Power Options).

Comment: It was set to "Blank".  I changed it to "None" and we'll see how that goes.  Can you make your suggestion an answer so I can give you credit (including the bounty) if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a screen saver, try and set it to "None" and see if this changes anything.
Screen display can be powered off after idle in Power Options.

As "sfc /scannow" did not find anything,
another diagnostic tool that you can do is described in
[Use PowerCfg in Windows 7 to Evaluate Power Efficiency](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/).
See if this finds any problem.

See also if there are any funny error messages in the Event Viewer.

If nothing is found, 
then there is only one hope left before drastic measures are called for - that
the problem is caused by some installed program.

Therefore I suggest to boot in Safe mode, let the computer sleep a few times
and see if it wakes up correctly each time.

If it does : Then the problem is not with Windows but with some installed program.
Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to turn selectively off startup programs until you find the culprit.

If nothing suspicious is found, then we start getting into deep water.
The last step before reinstalling Windows is as described here in this article:
[How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: Didn't work.  Feel free to edit the answer or post another one with another suggestion.

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: That's more than an answer - that's a MANswer!  Well done!  I'll give that stuff a try!